# hotspot was closed event

Tags: android, wifi

How to know wifi hotspot was close by user? I asume that there should have event to notify hotspot state changed. I looked into WifiManager.java, I found a releated action.

below action is hiden,

> public static final String WIFI_AP_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION = 
>   "android.net.wifi.WIFI_AP_STATE_CHANGED";

can you give me some point to get known hotspot was closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done using broadcast receiver for WIFI_AP_STATE_CHANGED.

Declare the receiver in Manifest as **android.net.wifi.WIFI_AP_STATE_CHANGED** action and include all necessory permissions to use WiFi. The on receive function of Broadcast receiver is as follows

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if ("android.net.wifi.WIFI_AP_STATE_CHANGED".equals(action)) {

            int hotSpotState = intent.getIntExtra("wifi_state", 
                                    0);

            // Your code goes here

        }
    }
```